# OpenGL mixes colors for GL_TEXTURE_3D in compute shader

Tags: opengl-es, compute-shader, 3d-texture

I am not sure whether it is a driver bug but following happens:

**compute-shader.glsl**:

```
#version 320 es
precision mediump float;

layout(local_size_x = 16, local_size_y = 8, local_size_z = 1) in;
layout(rgba8ui, binding = 0) writeonly uniform mediump uimage2D image;
layout(binding = 1) uniform mediump usampler3D grid;

void main() {
    uint i = gl_GlobalInvocationID.y;
    uint j = gl_GlobalInvocationID.x;

    uvec4 val = texture(grid, vec3(float(i)/480.0,float(j)/640.0,0.5));

    imageStore(image, ivec2(j,i), val);
}
```

The color channels of `val` are completely scrambled:

- *alpha* = *blue*
- *red = red*
- *green* = *alpha*
- *blue* = *green*

**main.cpp**:

```
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_3D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D, grid_tex_id);
    glTexStorage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 1, GL_RGBA8, 256, 256, 256);
    glTexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, 0, 0, 0, 256, 256, 256, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, grid.data);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

Is there any reasonable explanation for this? Note: I do not want to use the hack `val.ragb` (if that even exists).

Comment: Do you have any evidence that `grid.data` is in RGBA order?

Comment: Yes I do, I did the same example with ```uimage3D``` instead ```usampler3D``` which worked just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> layout(binding = 1) uniform mediump usampler3D grid;
> ...
> glTexStorage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 1, GL_RGBA8, 256, 256, 256);
> ```

`GL_RGBA8` is not an integer format; it's a *normalized* format. That means it is equivalent to a floating-point format. So you should use `sampler3D`, not `usampler3D`. Or you should upload your data to an integer format like `GL_RGBA8UI`, using the `GL_RGBA_INTEGER` pixel transfer format.

You probably got away with it using Image Load/Store by [re-specifying the format in the shader itself](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Load_Store#Format_conversion). You can't do that with textures.

Comment: just a little feedback. It seems like the ```GL_RGBA8UI```/ ```GL_RGBA_INTEGER```/ ```GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE``` is not filterable. See https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man3/html/glTexStorage3D.xhtml